# How to map one-to-many relation properly in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities, `Event` (it's movie in cinema actually) and `Ticket`.

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToOne
    private Movie movie;
    @Embedded
    private Auditorium auditorium;
    private LocalDateTime startDateTime;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "event")
    private List<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
// getters/setters, etc.
```

`Event` contains list of `Ticket`'s to sell, and every `Ticket` should point to exactly one `Event`.

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Event.class)
    private Event event;
    @OneToOne
    private User user;
    @Embedded
    private Seat seat;
    private TicketState state;
    private Float price;
// getters/setters, etc.
```

I have `EventService` with such a method (`Auditorium` contains only amount of seats and numbers of VIP seats), `bookingDao` just save `Ticket` in DB:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean assignAuditorium(Integer eventId, Auditorium auditorium, LocalDateTime datetime) {
        for (Event event : getAll()) {
            if (auditorium.equals(event.getAuditorium()) && intersectsWithAnotherEvent(event, datetime)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        Event currentEvent = getById(eventId);
        currentEvent.setAuditorium(auditorium);
        currentEvent.setStartDateTime(datetime);
        List<Ticket> tickets = currentEvent.getTickets();
        Integer seatsNumber = auditorium.getSeatsNumber();
        List<Integer> vipSeats = auditorium.getVipSeats();
        for (int i = 1; i <= seatsNumber; i++) {
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            ticket.setEvent(currentEvent);
            ticket.setState(TicketState.FREE);
            ticket.setSeat(new Seat(i, vipSeats.contains(i) ? SeatStatus.VIP : SeatStatus.STANDARD));
            bookingDao.create(ticket);
            tickets.add(ticket);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is: after creation of, f.e. 10 `Ticket`'s (according to amount of seats in `Auditorium`) I have 10 (!!!) identical `Event`'s as a result of `eventService.getAll()` with list of `Ticket`'s of size 10, each ticket has proper `Event` (as expected), instead of one `Event`.

So, how to map these entities properly to have one-event-to-many-tickets? Thank you!

**UPDATE** Implementation of `getAll()`

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Event> getAll() {
    return eventDao.getAll();
}

@Override
public List<Event> getAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Event.class).list();
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE2** I have such a picture right after the end of `assignAuditorium` method, suppose, then `@Transactional` ends to work. Than I'm inside this method `getAll()` shows one `Event` with list of `Ticket`'s as expected. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Please post the implementation of `eventService.getAll()` method.

Comment: @venkat Could you, please, explain what should I fix for annotations? I have no experience with XML Hibernate descriptions at all.

Comment: Ok.. can you have a look at below link. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Comment: I tried [this](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-onetomany-bidirectional-relationship/) approach , it seems the same as by your link - with no luck, I had several equal Event's for every Ticket

Comment: Updated with image for clarification

Comment: @Joydip Datta It doesn't let hold list of reference objects, as IDEA told me

Comment: @JoydipDatta, ElementCollection annotation is used when object which are not entities are embedded in an entity. In this case, Ticket and Event both are entities. So it should be not used. http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/31/jpa-elementcollection-annotation/

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin, have you established bidirectional relationship between Event and Ticket? This article could help. http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/18/jpa-one-many-mapping/

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar I've updated source code, I tried "cascade", "mappedBy", etc.

Comment: @DmitriiAdonin, you are rightly setting an event for each ticket. But for bidirectional relationship, you also need to put the list of tickets for each particular event. Have you done that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104239/discussion-between-prasad-kharkar-and-dmitrii-adonin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is caused by the EAGER fetch type on your one to many association. My first advice would be to leave it lazy: you really don't want to load the 250 tickets every time you want to get some information about an event. I would probably even avoid the OneToMany association.

But, in order to solve this, you need to use distinct. Either by adding a DistinctRootEntity result transformer to your criteria query or, preferrably, by using a JPQL query instead of a criteria query:

```
select distinct e from Event e
```

Comment: It seems you are quite right! Thank you very much - it works!